# No need for ViewModelLocator if using RegisterForNavigation?

Tags: prism

In prism we can have ViewModelLocator resolve the VM when we navigate to a View by setting the attached property `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"`

However, in the PRISM samples on Github, the container is initialized using the extension method (RegisterForNavigation) which seems to do the same thing.... ,

`containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();`

I am wondering if the RegisterForNavigation has made the AutowireViewModel attached property approach obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if the RegisterForNavigation has made the AutowireViewModel attached property approach obsolete?

No, this kind of registration just - additionally - defines the view model to be used for the registered view directly (instead of relying on the convention configured in the view model locator).

Setting `ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel` is still required to actually create the view model (whether it's type is defined manually or derived from the view's type by a convention).